# Derivative of the Frobenius norm of a matrix involving the Hadamard product

Tags: hadamard-product, frobenius-method

I want to take a derivative with respect to $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ but I have a problem.

The function is

$$f=\left\|\left(B_{1}^TA_{1}\right)\circ\left(B_{2}^TA_{2}\right)\circ\dotsb\circ\left(B_{N}^TA_{N}\right)\right\|_{F}^2$$ Where $\circ$ is Hadamrad product and $B_{1}^TA_{1}$ is a normal matrix multiplication.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you define the connection between $A$ and $A_1, A_2,...$ ? The same for $B$ and $B_1, B_2,...$ is it their numbered columns ?

Comment: Actually, I edit my question. There are few mistakes. So A is the tensor and $A_{n}$ is the n-mode matricization of A. $B_{n}^TA_{n}$ is R by R matrix.

Comment: $A$ is a tensor, but with which dimensions ? $n$ node matricization ? What is that ? Personaly, although familiar with Hadamard and Frobenius, I don't understand what you mean ... I wish you that somebody understands...

Comment: So let me change the formulation of the problem. $f={  ||(B^{T} A) \circ C ||_{F}^2}$ where  $C$  and $B^{T}A$ are R by R matrix. I want derivative with respect to B and A. Thank you