# Derivative of the Frobenius norm of a matrix involving the Hadamard products

Tags: derivatives, hadamard-product, frobenius-method

I want to take a derivative with respect to $A$ and $B$ but I have a problem.
The function is

$$f=\left\|\left(B^TA\right)\circ C\right\|_{F}^2$$ Where $\circ$ is Hadamrad product and $B^TA$ is a normal matrix multiplication. $B^TA$ and $C$ both are R by R matrix.
Thank you.

Comment: You have chose to write a new question after the one you asked 2 hours before (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2245684), following our discussion. Thus, you should delete the former one.

Answer (score 1):

$$B^t(A+ t a) \circ C = t B^t a \circ C.$$
Now, the Frobenius norm squared is just the inner product of the matrix with itself, so we get that the derivative is just $$2 (B^t a) \circ C.$$ All this because all the operations involved (except the final norm squared) are linear.

Comment: what are $t$ and $a$? Thank you.

Comment: $t a $ is a small perturbation of $A,$ so $t$ is a small real number, and $a$ is an arbitrary matrix.

Comment: Thank you. Is it the derivative with respect to A? by the way, is it possible to introduce useful resources?

Comment: @ari.afshar Yes, $B$ is similar.

Comment: Why you solve it with small perturbation approach? The problem  has a direct solution

Comment: @ari.afshar This IS a direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

To streamline the calculation, define the matrix
$$M=C\circ(B^TA)$$
Write the function in terms of the inner/Frobenius product
and this new matrix
$$f = M:M$$
Then find an expression for the differential
$$\eqalign{
df&= 2M:dM \cr
 &= 2M:C\circ d(B^TA) \cr
 &= 2(C\circ M):(dB^TA+B^TdA) \cr
 &= 2(C\circ M)A^T:dB^T + 2B(C\circ M):dA \cr
 &= 2A(C\circ M)^T:dB  + 2B(C\circ M):dA \cr
}$$
Therefore the gradients are
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= 2B(C\circ M) \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial B} &= 2A(C^T\circ M^T) \cr\cr
}$$